# overriding static vars in subclasses swift 1.2

Tags: swift

unlike `class` var, where they can overridden in subclasses, I believe same applies to `static` as well but unfortunately not. Here's an example

```
public class A {
    private static let NAME: String = "A"
}

public class B: A {
    private static let NAME: String = "B" //error
}
```

in my opinion static means association with that particular class, so in the above example `B` should get it's own space to redefine that variable as it's associated to `B` only, I'm reverting to `stored properties` unless someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [documentation](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3_beta_3/Xcode_6.3_beta_3_Release_Notes.pdf) says:

> “
>   static
>   ” methods and properties are now allowed in classes (as an alias for “
>   class final
>   ”).

So it is `final`, which means you cannot override it.

Answer (score 38):

You can use computed properties:

```
class A {
   class var Name: String {
       return "A"
   }
}

class B: A {
   override class var Name: String {
       return "B"
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
print(A.Name) // "A"
print(B.Name) // "B"
```

Comment: Work!. But IDE not help, with cmd + space

Answer (score 18):

As suggested, you cannot override static variables but can use class (static) function to override.

```
class A {
   class func StaticValue() -> AnyObject {
      return "I am a String"
   }
}

class B: A {
    override class func StaticValue() -> AnyObject {
        return 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have **computed** class properties:

```
public class A {
   class var NAME: String {
       return "A"
   }
}

public class B {
   class var NAME: String {
       return "B"
   }
}
```

If need be, you could even "branch" to a stored property in the subclass:

```
public class A {
       // Needs to be overriden in subclass
       class var NAME: String {
           return "A"
       }
    }

public class B {
   class var NAME: String {
       return B.storedName
   }

   static var storedName: String = defineName()

   func defineName() -> String {
       // You could do something more complex here
       return "B"
   }
}
```

Comment: Excellent hints. Just a few remarks - I believe your intention was `public class B: A` not `public class B`. Also you have to add `override` keyword `override class var name: String`. Not fully understand your intention with `static var storedName: String = defineName()`, because you can't use instance method to initialize static/class properties.