# Why can we use 'static' in a class of Swift language?

Tags: swift, class, static

Normally we should use keyword `class` to define a class computed property,
like

```
class Square{
    class var area:Float{
        return 100.0*100.0
    } 
}
```

However we can not use `class` to define a stored property (I know it results from OC).

And meanwhile we may use `static` in a class to define a stored property and it runs successfully.

[image]

So my question is: what are the differences between `static` and `class` when used in a class?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between `static` and `class` is that `class` elements can be overridden.

As a short way to say this, `static` has the same effect that `final class`.

You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156377/what-is-the-difference-between-static-func-and-class-func-in-swift) to have more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189700/overriding-static-vars-in-subclasses-swift-1-2/29215714#29215714), basically, you can override a `class` `func`/`var`, but you cannot a `static` one.